# Problema con Cambio de hora del Servidor HP DL 360 g9

Tags: servidor

Tengo instalado en un servidor HP DL 360 g9 un Windows Server 2012R. Configuro la hora y luego de un tiempo vuelve y se cambia.

Revisando me arroja este mensaje:
The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎08‎-‎24T15:45:18.985000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎08‎-‎24T15:45:17.074582200Z.

Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.

que puede ser ?

Comment: Revisa en el siguiente link, te puede servir. Muy buena pregunta. http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c04557232